# Parallax scrolling not working consistetly on Chrome.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a webpage with parallax scrolling. Everything is looking great on my localhost, but the parallax scrolling doesn't work consistently once I upload the page to my server.

Once in the server it doesn't work consistently as the objects traveling at different speed in the browser window start doing so too soon.

The odd is that if I refresh the page parallax works as intended, but if I refresh again it goes back to previous version. Then if I refresh again it works again....

I'm only having this issue with Chrome (default and incognito browser)

Did anyone else ran into this issue? I'm loosing my mind here. I would really appreciate any help on how to troubleshoot this one.

Comment: Post your code or create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

My first guess at what is going on, (based on my experience):

Most browsers cache content (like Javascript and CSS) so they don't have to keep re-loading it  and to speed up the page load-time.

When you refresh the page multiple times (quickly), or when you hold down the shift key and press the refresh button, most browsers will reload all of the content (the javascript that you changed), not just the HTML.  This means that your newly changed javascript should be re-loaded and work with any HTML that you may have changed.

I have this problem when I'm developing websites.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Chrome has setting labeled *"Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"* - sounds like you should check it out ;)